# How to conditionally include into "Compiled Sources" in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building a Library for ios. Now, I would like to compile two versions of this Library based on preprocessors. Now, in second versions, I may not require all files so I remove files from "Compiled Sources" in "Build Phases" manually. Is there any automatic way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the way to go with this kind of situation in XCode is to create two different targets for the same project, each with the right sources to be compiled.

Comment: I guess you are right. I thought of the same approach earlier. Will go with that. Thank you.